# Parsing XML using Linq in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, combobox

I am having an issue parsing an XML file and getting the results I am expecting.  The scenario is I select an option out of a combobox.  I have two options which I am returning from the XML file ("Cash Disbursements" and "Journal").  The problem I am having is the population of the next combobox.  The values I am getting to populate the combobox with is with all of the "column name names".

*Below is a list of my XML.*

```xml
<file_import_types>
    <importtypes>
        <types import_type_name="Cash Disbursements">
            <type name="This - IS the name I want" import="Payments" uniquecol="2" countcol="5" ft="C">
                <columns>
                    <column name="test" Type="Double" Literal="1" GLNumber="0" Vend or="0" Format="" />
                    <column name="123" Type="String" Literal="1" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="String" />
                    <column name="Tester" Type="String" Literal="0" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="String" />
                    <column name="DATE" Type="DateTime" Literal="0" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="Date" />
                    <column name="test_again" Type="Double" Literal="1" GLNumber="1" Vendor="0" Format="" />
                    <column name="CountTest" Type="Double" Literal="0" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="" />
                    <column name="BlankTest" Type="DBNull" Literal="1" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="" />
                    <column name="DESCRIPTION" Type="String" Literal="0" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="String" />
                    <column name="NumberTest" Type="Double" Literal="0" GLNumber="1" Vendor="0" Format="" />
                    <column name="Thisisjustatest" Type="Double" Literal="0" GLNumber="0" Vendor="0" Format="Money" />
                </columns>
            </type>
        </types>
    </importtypes>
</file_import_types>
```

*Here is my code:*

```vb
'ACHFileType is the name of my second combobox that I am trying to populate.
ACHFileType.Items.Clear()
Dim importDefinitionElement As XElement = _
    (From xmlDefinitions As XElement In xmlFile.Descendants _
     Where xmlDefinitions.Attribute("import_type_name") = cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString) _
    .FirstOrDefault
Dim query = From xmlDefinition As XElement In importDefinitionElement.Descendants Where xmlDefinition.Name = "type"
Dim formatType2 As New List(Of String)
Dim type As String = cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 1)

For Each xmlColumn As XElement In query
    ' Loops through Columns in Excel
    If xmlColumn.Attribute("ft").Value.ToString = type Then
        For Each g As XAttribute In query.Elements.Elements.Attributes("name")
            Debug.Print(g.Value.ToString)
            formatType2.Add(g.Value)
        Next
    End If
Next

For Each a As String In formatType2
    ACHFileType.Items.Add(a.ToString())
    'The values that get populated here are "test", "123", "Tester", etc...  The value I am expecting is "This - Is the name I want"
Next
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The values that are returning are "test", "123", "Tester"... etc.  The value I am looking for is the top type name= "This - IS the name I want."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Dim query = From xmlDefinition As XElement In importDefinitionElement.Descendants Where xmlDefinition.Name = "type"` is getting you the `XElement` for the `type` tag, then just do this:

```
Dim value = CType(query.Attribute("name"), String)
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type '<GetAttributes>d__8' to type 'System.String'. was the error I received when I tried to "Dim value = CType(query.Attributes("name"), String)...  Unless I am misunderstanding your direction.  I am new to linq, sorry.

Comment: For Each g As XAttribute In query.Attributes("name")
            Debug.Print(g.Value.ToString)
            ACHFileType.Items.Add(g.Value)
        Next

I used that instead of 

                For Each g As XAttribute In query.Elements.Elements.attributes("name")
            Debug.Print(g.Value.ToString)
            ACHFileType.Items.Add(g.Value)
        Next

I also removed the other for loop to count the columns because it was duplicating the data.  I also removed the final for loop because I can write the data directly into the combobox instead of a list first.

Comment: Is `query` an `XElement` on the line where you try to get `.Attribute("name")`?

Comment: Try running just this code: `Dim importDefinitionElement As XElement = _ (From xmlDefinitions As XElement In xmlFile.Descendants _ Where xmlDefinitions.Attribute("import_type_name") = cbFilter.SelectedItem.ToString) _ .FirstOrDefault
Dim query = From xmlDefinition As XElement In importDefinitionElement.Descendants Where xmlDefinition.Name = "type" Dim value = CType(query.Attribute("name"), String)`, does that work?